# How do I use same method in different Java projects

Tags: java

I use method A in several different Java projects. Is there a way to write the method just once and then call it as required from different Java projects?

Answer (score 6):

Create a class with that method. Create a jar for this class. Use this jar in all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Define `public` class and define at least `public` or `protected` method. Then import that class in your new project's class and use it.
`default` classes with `public` or `protected` methods are not accessible in different projects/packages even if default class' methods are `public/protected`. 
So use public class and public or protected methods and at last create a jar with this file and add this jar file in your project to use.